# Enzyme/Jest -- Writing TDD with DOM tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

Using shallow component, how do I test something like this that has DOM API (querySelector for instance)

```
handleOnClick(e) {
    const { pageID } = this.props
    document.querySelector('form .event').name = '_eventID' + pageID
    document.querySelector('form').submit()
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

My test is breaking because in TDD, the `document` does not exist.

Is there way I can inject a mock `document` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a `global` document object manually with just the functions you need to test, or you can use something like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). Your best bet may be to follow the [enyzme recommendation on document injection](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html).